# Distance nearest hub with conditions

Tags: qgis-processing, proximity, qgis-3

I have 3 shapefile: pipes (line), junctions (point), customers (point). I want to bring customer demand value from customer to junctions with conditions:

1. First condition: Nearest road
2. Second condition: the nearest node

I used "Distances nearest hub" but it only gives the result for second condition.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

[image]